# WSL 1 keeps crashing with error code 0xd00002fe

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

My WSL installation with Ubuntu 22.04 has been crashing of late (ever since I upgraded to WSL version 1.0.3.0). I have not been able to figure out the cause of the crash. What has happened in every instance so far is that I leave the WSL window open in the background, doing whatever with other programs in Windows. Then at some point when I have some use for WSL, I alt-tab to the WSL window and find the following:

```
Error: 0xd00002fe
Error code: Wsl/Service/0xd00002fe
Press any key to continue...
```

When I press a key, the WSL window closes on its own. When I start WSL back up, it starts normally and works fine, but eventually it crashes again in the manner described above.

Running `wsl.exe --version` in PowerShell displays the following:

```
WSL version: 1.0.3.0
Kernel version: 5.15.79.1
WSLg version: 1.0.47
MSRDC version: 1.2.3575
Direct3D version: 1.606.4
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.19044.2486
```

Googling around has not turned up any similar reports. I am not very knowledgeable about WSL so I don't know how to debug this further. Any suggestions on how to further investigate these crashes or a fix would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have *System cryptography: Use FIPS compliant algorithms for encryption, hashing, and signing* enabled or disabled? **0xd00002fe** is linked to a networking problem. Why WSL1 when WSL2 is the suggested version? I presume your not installing WSL through the Windows Store since your setting the version to WSL1?

Comment: That setting is disabled. I believe I installed through the Windows Store back when WSL1 was still the main version (and I heard some stability issues with WSL2 so did not want to install that). Perhaps I should just install WSL2 instead.

Comment: If you installed back when only WSL1 existed then it was impossible for you to install WSL through the Windows Store, you might have installed the distribution from the Windows Store, but that wasn't what I was asking. There are no stability issues with WSL2.

Comment: Ok, I've switched to WSL2 using `wsl --set-version Ubuntu-20.04 2`.

Comment: WSL2 is not properly integrated - it has a separate network stack (so localhost comms does not work properly between Windows and WSL) and is horribly slow when accessing files on the Windows partition. (You also can't manage processes from Windows) (It is like Virtualbox in seamless mode (similar to WSL2) compared to Wine)

Comment: Any hibernation involved? (My similar issues seems to potentially be after restoring from hibernation)

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/9563  I see that issue for WSL2....

Comment: @GertvandenBerg I do close my laptop at night, which should put it in sleep mode but not hibernation (but maybe Windows does not actually have this distinction or it automatically hibernates after a while as stated in that GitHub issue). It's likely that all of the crashes I experienced happened after putting the computer to sleep and waking back up.

Comment: @riceissa Ah, mine also - mine is set to always hibernate (there is a "hybrid sleep" option that saves data for both methods) (I dislike sleep mode - it drains the battery and hibernation restore from SSDs is reasonably quick)

Comment: @GertvandenBerg It seems like mine is set to sleep, not hibernate https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9YSn.png

Comment: Windows Terminal has an issue that it gets closed if the Windows Store updates it... I wonder if that is what is happening to WSL. (I switched off my auto-updates in the Windows Store now)

Comment: @GertvandenBerg fwiw I have not experienced this issue ever since switching to WSL2, but I assume you don't want to do that.